# Do I need to remove System.Data and System.Data.Common while upgrading EF5 to EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-4.8

I'm following Microsoft Guide and it mentions that

- Ensure that assembly references to System.Data.Entity.dll are removed
- The general rule for namespace changes is that any type in
  System.Data.* is moved to System.Data.Entity.Core.*.

But my projects are using ADO.NET Objects such as:

- 'DbException'
- 'DataException'
- 'DbCommand'
- 'IDbDataParameter'
- 'DbType'
- 'IDbCommand'

How can I replace them? I'm looking these namespaces

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

But couldn't find any replacement.

Is it still okay to use *System.Data* and *System.Data.Common* namespaces? If not, how can I replace them?

Comment: Entity Framework also uses ADO.NET objects. EF isn't a data access library, it's an ORM that works on top of ADO.NET. EF generates the SQL commands that get executed by ADO.NET.  In any case, EF 5 is very old - it was released in 2012. Even EF 6 is 10 years old, released in 2013. When it was first released MS was still trying to make everyone use its products, hence everything, including the SQL Server client, was in the `System.Data` namespace.

Answer (score 3):

Below fragment from that [Upgrading to Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/upgrading-to-ef6#4-update-namespaces-for-any-core-ef-types-being-used) article, is to be read as that the mentioned namespace changes are to be applied on types that are in the `System.Data.*` namespace **and** originate from the `System.Data.Entity.dll` assembly.

> Types like `ObjectContext` that were previously in `System.Data.Entity.dll` have been moved to new namespaces. This means you may need to update your using or Import directives to build against EF6.

> The general rule for namespace changes is that any type in `System.Data.*` is moved to `System.Data.Entity.Core.*`.

The `System.Data.Common` namespace of e.g. the [`DbException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbexception) type matches that namespace, but `DbException` is in the `System.Data.Common.dll` assembly, not in `System.Data.Entity.dll`.

For that reason `DbException` is still fine to be used, as are the other types you mentioned.

---

Entity Framework 6 itself makes use of types from the `System.Data.Common` namespace, see [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/ef6/blob/99c172bc465492fa37f9efa07900653975ec79b4/src/EntityFramework/Core/Common/DbCommandDefinition.cs#L5)

That article also has below note about the `System.Data` namespace.

> Some types in the `System.Data` namespace are in `System.Data.dll` which is not an EF assembly. These types have not moved and so their namespaces remain unchanged.